# Topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tau = \{G: \text{$G$ is finite or $G^\complement$ is finite} \}$

Tags: general-topology

I don’t think this is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. If we take all elements in $\mathbb{Q}$ as singltons, then each singleton belongs to $\tau$ and we take arbitrary union (countable union) then this becomes $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't belong to $\tau$.

But $\tau = \{G: \text{$G$ is countable or $G^\complement$ is countable} \}$ is a topology.

Can anyone verify?

Comment: It is not a topology for similar reason: consider $V=\bigcup_{x\in [0,1]}\{x\}$: it is a union of countable (singletons) sets but it is neither countable nor its complement is.

Comment: Got it sir. Thanks!